# ElectronJS Dependency Problem with Buildroot

Tags: electron, chromium, dbus, alsa, buildroot

I'm trying to run ElectronJS app to Buildroot-based Operating System for a vehicle instrument. The SBC is Raspberry Pi 4B and target packages are included based on [Debian's dependencies list](https://packages.debian.org/buster/chromium). Then after I run the app, it throws this message:

```sh
# DISPLAY=:0 ./my-app --no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox
./my-app: /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2: no version information available (required by ./my-app)
./my-app: /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2: no version information available (required by ./my-app)
/root/my-app: /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2: no version information available (required by /root/my-app)
/root/my-app: /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2: no version information available (required by /root/my-app)
/root/my-app: /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2: no version information available (required by /root/my-app)
/root/my-app: /usr/lib64/libasound.so.2: no version information available (required by /root/my-app)
[1763:0101/075845.947675:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
Trace/breakpoint trap
# _
```

Keep in mind that [glxgears](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/benchmarking#glxgears) and [glxinfo](https://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/glxinfo/) are working perfectly. The frame rate is around 198 FPS. Thus, GPU supposed to not be blamed.

I am pretty sure something wrong with ALSA libraries or DBUS, perhaps anyone experiencing same problem? Thanks!

Comment: I believe I am seeing similar.  I hadn't seen your post, so posted a question [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/136506/pi4-electron-gui-using-buildroot).  I do not have a solution to offer unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Adding `{ frame: false, fullscreen: true }` in the electron `BrowserWindow` constructor options make it work.

Comment: Turns out that I already [added it to the source code](https://github.com/ventros-project/core-electron/blob/5fed234fa4b1420652ac30cf5f61be3a90055a09/main.js#L32) and still has the issue

Comment: For the d-bus error logs, using `DISPLAY=:0 dbus-launch ./my-app --no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox` should fix dbus error logs. Do you have enabled "alsa-lib" in Target packages → Libraries → Audio/Sound build root config ?

Comment: Sorry for late response, @angelodlfrtr It's already installed but it's using Wayland instead of Xorg-server (EDIT: revert to Xorg-server and still same, perhaps buildroot bug?)